# Symfony 3: Call default validator inside a Custom Validator and check it the field is validated

Tags: symfony

I have a custom validator where I'm getting the value of one of the fields defined in my entity, and then I want to validate that field using built in validator (ex. NotBlank()) so that after a validation I get 'true' in case the field is validated and 'false' if it's not.

My custom validator looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;


class UpdatePasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function validate($email, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        /**
         * Getting field value from entity
         */
        $busNumber = $this->context->getRoot()->getData()->getBusnumber();

        /**
         * Validate $busNumber
         */
        $busNumberToValidate = $this->context->getValidator()
            ->inContext($this->context)
            ->atPath("busnumber")
            ->validate($busNumber, new NotBlank())->getViolations();
    }
}
```

In this case I want to validate $busNumber using NotBlank().
Calling getViolations() gives me an object with all violations while I just need one that is associated with the $busNumber validation.

Update: what I'm actually trying to achieve is this:

```
if ($busNumberToValidate)
{
    echo "busNumber field is validated";
}
else
{
    echo "busNumber field is NOT validated";    
}
```

The $busNumberToValidate should contain or not an error for 'busNumber' field depending on the validation result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
$busNumberToValidate = $this->context->getValidator()->validate($busNumber, new NotBlank());

if ($busNumberToValidate->has(0))
{
  echo "field is not validated";
}
else
{
  echo "field is validated";
}

// if you want to get the error message for the validated field 
echo $busNumberToValidate->get(0)->getMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend [Composite Constraint](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Composite.html)

You can find example in [All Constraint](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/All.html)

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I want to achieve. So I would like to know if it's possible to use if statement to check whether a validated field has errors or not. I've explained it in update.